# How to return the users in a domain local group in Powershell

Tags: powershell

When I run the following command on a domain local group:

```powershell
Get-ADGroupMember "Name of Group"
```

I get the following output:

```powershell
Get-ADGroupMember : The operation completed successfully
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember "Name of Group"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Name of Group:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The operation completed successfully,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

When I run the command on a global group, I get the output of the users in the group. Is there a way to get the users from a domain local group?

Comment: Command you are running works whether the group is domain local or not.

Comment: That was the only difference in the groups that I noticed.

Comment: Must be something else

Comment: Is this a multiple-domain or multi-forest setup?

Comment: There are multiple domains, but I'm only trying for groups in a specific domain.

Comment: Are your computer in the same domain as the group your querying? If not, you may need to specify `-Server myseconddomain.com`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this doesn't work:

```powershell
Get-ADGroup "Name of Group" | Get-ADGroupMember
```

Try the following:

```powershell
$s = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADGroup "Name of Group").DistinguishedName
([ADSI]$s).member
```

Comment: I get this error when I try:

Get-ADGroupMember : The operation completed successfully
At line:1 char:36
+ Get-ADGroup "Name of Group" | Get-ADGroupMember
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=AZ Region Mo...C=corp,DC=com:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The operation completed successfully,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: Does `Get-ADGroup "Name of Group"` by itself return the correct group?

Comment: Added another answer. If you still get an error try both suggestions and after each run `$error[0] | fl * -force`. This will output a more verbose error which you should attach to the question rather than adding it to the comments.

Comment: the second method worked for me but i cant figure out how to get the name and userprincipalname from these results.  how do i take this command one step further and get the names of the users? i started out doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26921869/get-a-list-of-users-from-a-domain-local-group-in-active-directory) but got stuck.

Comment: It's best to ask a new question and refer back to this one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to export the users from a domain local group use this code:

```
$s = "LDAP://" + (Get-ADGroup "Name of Group").DistinguishedName

([ADSI]$s) | select -ExpandProperty member| select @{Name=’members‘;Expression={[string]::join(“;”, ($_))}} | export-csv C:\Path\File.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Warning: if you have users from another domain in the domain local group they will appear as SIDs.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this error when looking at distribution groups. - I got no error, but the 4 members of the group were not listed. I was convinced it was because it was a domain local group.

I had set the recipient scope to the entire forest (`Set-AdServerSettings -ViewEntireForest $true`). For whatever reason, if you do that, you should use the DN (rather than alias or name) to get the members, and also include the switch `-ReadFromDomainController`. So, I had to use

```
Get-DistributionGroupMember -Identity DistinguishedName -ReadFromDomainController
```